# Google App Engine webchat with external SSO

Tags: google-app-engine, authorization, single-sign-on, saml

I created a simple webchat using Google app engine and Dialogflow. The functions of webchat are not important here, what is important is that I want to authorize the SSO of my university to use one of the functionalities of the webchat (yes, my project is a diploma thesis).
I contacted the university and they said that they could give me access to the test SSO, they also provided https. They noted that their recommended protocol is SAML2 and I was asked for metadata. And here is my problem - I don't know where to get them. I've read a bit about this on the internet, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.
May I ask for some advice?